# IBpy cannot cancel open orders placed manually

Tags: ibpy

When using ibpy trying to close some positions placed on TWS manually, it turns our we could not do this. Specifically, when performing:

```
    self._tws.reqAllOpenOrders()
    sleep(0.2)
```

We get the orders with id 0 (probably because i placecd it manually on TWS)

```
<openOrder orderId=0, contract=<ib.ext.Contract.Contract object at 0x103b78ad0>, order=<ib.ext.Order.Order object at 0x103b78a50>, orderState=<ib.ext.OrderState.OrderState object at 0x103b78b10>>
<orderStatus orderId=0, status=Submitted, filled=0, remaining=100, avgFillPrice=0.0, permId=134994568, parentId=0, lastFillPrice=0.0, clientId=0, whyHeld=None>
<openOrder orderId=0, contract=<ib.ext.Contract.Contract object at 0x103b78c90>, order=<ib.ext.Order.Order object at 0x103b78c50>, orderState=<ib.ext.OrderState.OrderState object at 0x103b78cd0>>
<orderStatus orderId=0, status=Submitted, filled=0, remaining=1, avgFillPrice=0.0, permId=134994562, parentId=0, lastFillPrice=0.0, clientId=0, whyHeld=None>
<openOrderEnd>
```

When trying to close it with:

```
    self._tws.cancelOrder(0)
```

or

```
    self._tws.cancelOrder(134994568)
```

I get the error:

```
<error id=0, errorCode=135, errorMsg=Can't find order with id =0>
<error id=134994562, errorCode=135, errorMsg=Can't find order with id =134994562>
```

Any idea how could we close them? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to 'bind' the orders to the new client.  Use this method `tws.reqAutoOpenOrders(True)`.  From the docs,

> Finally, IBApi.EClient.reqAutoOpenOrders will allow to obtain those
>   orders manually placed using the TWS itself. This method also allows
>   the client application to take over these orders and modify them by
>   setting the autoBind parameter to true. If successfully bound, The
>   orders will be assigned (i.e. bound to) an API order id and as such be
>   eligible for modification.
>
> client.reqAutoOpenOrders(true); Important: only those applications connecting with client Id 0 will be able to take over
>   manually submitted orders
>
> Through the TWS' API settings it is possible to configure this
>   method's behaviour to some extent. As shown in the image below,
>   manually placed orders can be given a negative order Id which can
>   serve to easily tell manual from API submitted orders. The TWS'
>   tooltip elaborates further:

The callback will look like `<openOrder orderId=-3,...` and then you just call `tws.cancelOrder(-3)`

Note that you don't get orders placed previously in TWS, only those placed after the call to `reqAutoOpenOrders`.

Comment: Thank you very much. would you like to spend some time to answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289239/how-could-we-use-ibpy-for-editing-orders