# How could we use ibpy for editing orders?

Tags: ibpy

I know that in ibpy I could place order to create a new order:

```
    self._tws.placeOrder(order_id,contract, order)
```

However, suppose I know want to change the limit price of some already placed order. Is there anything like:?

```
    self._tws.editOrder(order_id,contract, order)
```

Or simply use place order with the specific order_id is ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just call placeOrder again with the same orderId but with changed data.  You can only change certain fields but m_lmtPrice is easy.

From the docs,

> Modification of an open order through the API can be achieved by the
>   same client which placed the original order. In the case of orders
>   placed manually in TWS, the order can be modified by the client with
>   ID 0.
>
> To modify an order, simply call the IBApi.EClient.placeOrder function
>   again with the same parameters used to place the original order,
>   except for the changed parameter. This includes the
>   IBApi.Order.OrderId, which must match the IBApi.Order.OrderId of the
>   original. It is not generally recommended to try to change order
>   parameters other than the order price and order size. To change other
>   parameters, it might be preferable to cancel the original order and
>   place a new order.

Link
http://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/modifying_orders.html#gsc.tab=0